# How to disable loading external urls on seleniumlibrary/robotframework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I started playing with Seleniumlibrary tests (run with robotframework) and as our websites have ads and metrics and so on, every time I run a test those URLs get loaded.

Is there a way to tell selenium/robotframework to not load certain types of URLs or prevent it to load external resources (i.e. everything that is not from localhost).

Answer (score 10):

You can do that with [browsermob-proxy](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/).  Once you have that installed, you simply setup the proxy and set the blacklist.

```
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(9000)
server.start();
final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, server.seleniumProxy());
//Send a 200 for all requests to the facebook cdn
server.blacklistRequests("http://.*\\.fbcdn.net/.*", 200); 
//Finish setting up your driver
WebDriver driver = new SomeDriverImpl(capabilities);
```

I believe the following will work with [this python wrapper](http://oss.theautomatedtester.co.uk/browsermob-proxy-py/) (the regex might be slightly different):

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
proxy.blacklist('http://.*\\.fbcdn.net/.*', 200)
from selenium import webdriver
profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
...
proxy.stop()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You didn't state which language you were using, so I assumed Java. Is this not correct? A quick search shows that there are many wrappers for that library for python.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm using python. Thanks for the response, will mark is as valid once I got around to try it!

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the dot in fbcdn.net, for example:

`server.blacklistRequests("https?://.*\\.fbcdn\\.net/.*", 200);`

Answer (score 2):

This can now be done in two lines in Chrome:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": ["www.baidu.com"]})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
```